# How to set minimum order amount for WooCommerce excluding shipping?

Tags: woocommerce

Is there a code to set minimum order amount for WooCommerce excluding shipping?

With this one I can set minimum order amount but with shipping:

```
/**
 * Set a minimum order amount for checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 16;

    if ( WC()->cart->total < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Стойност на Вашата поръчка: %s <p>Минималната стойност на поръчката към ресторанта: %s' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Стойност на Вашата поръчка: %s <p>Минималната стойност на поръчката към ресторанта: %s' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can just subtract the supping cost from the total using `WC()->cart->get_shipping_total()`

Comment: Can you post it as answer and include full code? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments,

You just need to subtract the cost of shipping from the cart total.
You can use the [`WC_Cart::get_shipping_total`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Cart.html#248-256) method.

It should look something like this:

```php
<?php
/**
 * Set a minimum order amount for checkout
 */
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_cart' , 'wc_minimum_order_amount' );

function wc_minimum_order_amount() {
    // Set this variable to specify a minimum order value
    $minimum = 16;
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->total; // Cart total incl. shipping
    $shipping_total = WC()->cart->get_shipping_total();  // Cost of shipping
    if ( ($cart_total - $shipping_total) < $minimum ) {

        if( is_cart() ) {

            wc_print_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Стойност на Вашата поръчка: %s <p>Минималната стойност на поръчката към ресторанта: %s' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        } else {

            wc_add_notice( 
                sprintf( 'Стойност на Вашата поръчка: %s <p>Минималната стойност на поръчката към ресторанта: %s' , 
                    wc_price( WC()->cart->total ), 
                    wc_price( $minimum )
                ), 'error' 
            );

        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: This code returns error: `Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in /home/dolcheam/public_html/wp-content/themes/dt-the7/functions.php on line 133` This line is 133: `if ( ($cart_total - $shipping_total) < $minimum ) {`

Comment: What version of Woocommerce are you using?

Comment: Wordpress 5.2.2 and Woocommerce 3.7.0

Comment: I've updated the code, `get_cart_total` is auto formats the price, we can either user `->cart->total` as you used or just use `get_cart_totals (null)` to make it not format.